# Самарянин или самаритянин?

Tags: орфоэпия

На одном сообществе разгорелся спор: как правильно говорить "самаритянин" или "самарянин"? Одни утверждали, что правильны обе формы, а другие, что "самарянин" — это житель Самары, а не Самарии.
Пожалуйста, помогите разрешить спор.

Comment: Очень интересно, что вопрос задан : "как правильно самарянин или самаритянин?"
А отвечают о названии жителей Самары..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Мнение филолога, жителя города Самары:
   "Все, что касается того, какое из названий - самарчане, самаряне или самарцы - следует употреблять по нормам языка, здесь действует критерий языкового вкуса. Абсолютно нормативно, с точки зрению русского языка, - самарцы. Это слово нейтрально для всех стилей и сфер. Все остальное - это просто демонстрация возможностей русской словообразовательной системы. И я бы не рекомендовала называть наших с Вами сограждан ни самарянами, ни самарчанами. И уж тем более неприятно, когда так нас называют со страниц газет и с экранов телевизоров".
2. Самаритяне - жители Самарии. Это слово образуется с непродуктивным суффиксом, для сравнения: Израиль - израильтянин. Называть так жителей Самары нельзя.

Самаритяне (самаряне) считают себя потомками жителей Израильского царства. Название народа и обозначение всей территории — Самария — происходит от названия последней столицы Израильского царства, основанной царём Амврием (Омри) и разрушенной Ассирией.

ВЫВОД: основной (нейтральный) вариант: самарцы, в разговорной речи - самарчане и самаряне, вариант " самаритяне" - ненормативный.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, самарянин - русское слово (в церковно-славянская библия) , самаритянин - иностранное слово (английский, французский, немецкий и пр.). Учёные люди любят поиностранней, простые люди - породнее. Каждый может выбрать.

Answer (score -1):

От историка. Исконное самоназвание, судя по источникам до середины XIX века, жителей Самары - "самаряне". Название было вытеснено притоком в город со второй половины 19-го солетия новопоселенцев, чужих местной традиции. На смену пришло слово "самарцы", новообразованное по усредненным правилам. Окончательно добили традицию советские времена, когда не было никакой Самары, а в городе Куйбышеве без всяких вариантов жили "куйбышевцы".  Слово "самарцы" - скучное и довольно неблагозвучное. Заметьте, как редко им пользуются в самой Самаре. Отсюда попытки в шутку или всерьез от него уйти. Особенно не подходит оно к прекрасному полу. Пару "самарцу" должна составить "самарка". Совсем звучит неприлично. Отсюда "самарочки", "самарчанки".

Comment: "самаритянин" или "самарянин"? Куйбышев и самарочки причем?